# apache mod_jk send request to all cluster nodes

Tags: apache, cluster-computing, load-balancing, sticky

I have a distrubuted cluster system. I have set up apache server and set loadbalancing (mod_jk) conditions. And also sticky session is true mode. 
Is it possible that could I send some special requests (after request header control) to all tomcat cluster nodes ? Is there any rule or method ?

There is no need to send back to clients, all nodes be informed from special url is enough. I have configured uriworkermap.properties, there are 3 status(active, disabled, stopped) for loadbalancer nodes. Is there any solution by configuring uriworkermap.properties or workers.properties?

For solution of this problem, suggesting alternatives of mod_jk ?

Comment: Among nodes, there is no multicasting. Normally every request goes one node but for some special url, I want to send these requests to all cluster nodes. For example for some url, application should not be seen to user

Comment: I see what you have in mind, but I don't think it's possible: For each (multiplied) request, there would also be a response coming back from the Tomcat instances. How should Apache decide which of the reponses it actually sends back to the client? Maybe it's easier to set up some kind of synchronizing between the Tomcats when a special request comes in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is not it possible that send broadcast message(not request) from load balancer to all tomcat cluster nodes ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session Replication between tomcat nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030367/session-replication-between-tomcat-nodes)