# mod_jk notify all tomcat instances

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apache mod_jk send request to all cluster nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383405/apache-mod-jk-send-request-to-all-cluster-nodes)

I have an apache server that mod_jk installed on and multiple tomcat instances running. When a request comes from a special url, I want to send this request to all tomcat instances or something like a notification that this request came. And I don't need any response returning from tomcats.

Is it possible with mod_jk? If not, is there a alternative to mod_jk that can do what I need ?

Comment: See [apache mod_jk send request to all cluster nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383405).

Comment: I looked at it.But it didn't help.Any other advice?