# Session Replication between tomcat nodes

Tags: session, tomcat, cluster-computing, tomcat7, sessionid

The tomcat doc of apache says, there are three ways, wecan achieve session replication among tomcat nodes -

1. Using session persistence, and saving the session to a shared file system (PersistenceManager + FileStore)
2. Using session persistence, and saving the session to a shared database (PersistenceManager + JDBCStore)
3. Using in-memory-replication, using the SimpleTcpCluster that ships with Tomcat 6 (lib/catalina-tribes.jar + lib/catalina-ha.jar)

In my application, I do use SINGLE cluster having TWO tomcat 7.0.25 nodes. I want to configure session replication between these two nodes.
Can anybody provide some points describing which one I should use and why ?

I am able to set up session replication using point 3. It works good.

I want to play with option 1 & 2 also. 
But not able to find out any link that describes point 1 & 2. It would be really very helpful if anyone can provide me some docs or links on point 1 & point 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this tutorial

[Persistent Session Manager and a shared file store / JDBC store to RDBMS](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_clustering.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There's some info on JDBCStore in the book "Apache Tomcat 7" By Aleksa Vukotic, James Goodwil:
http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-1JFHBvvGBgC&lpg=PA117&ots=1UTkoEFKbP&dq=PersistenceManager%20%2B%20JDBCStore&pg=PA117#v=onepage&q=PersistenceManager%20+%20JDBCStore&f=false

Comment: Thanks Thomos. It's really very helpful